# jQuery set class active and remove all other active classes

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a step wizard and everytime i press the "next" button the step wizard should remove the step1 active and set the next active to step 2.

I have written this:

jQuery:

```
$('#goto-step-four').click(function () {
    $("#step-one").removeClass();
    $("#step-two").removeClass();
    $("#step-three").removeClass();
    $("#step-four").toggleClass('active');
    $("#step-five").removeClass();
});
```

Step wizard:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified thumbnail">
          <li id ="step-one" class="active"><a id="step-one-button">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Stap 1</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">NAW gegevens klant</p>
              </a></li>
              <li id ="step-two" class=""><a id="step-two-button">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Stap 2</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">Selecteer een type</p>
              </a></li>
              <li id="step-three" class=""><a id="step-three-button">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Stap 3</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">Breedte en hoogte</p>
              </a></li>
              <li id="step-four" class=""><a id="step-four-button">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Stap 4</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">Extra's</p>
              </a></li>
              <li id="step-five" class="disabled"><a id="step-five-button">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Stap 5</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">Controleer gegevens</p>
              </a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

I think this is a bit messy and there should be a better way doing this. What can i do to make this cleaner?

Comment: Is this code within an event handler?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will update my code

Comment: show your html here

Comment: I have editted my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to put a common class on all the elements you want to group. You can then call `removeClass()` on them all together whilst calling `addClass()` to the element you want to target. Something like this:

```js
$('#goto-step-four').click(function () {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#step-four').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="goto-step-four">Step 4</button><br /><br />

<div class="step" id="step-one">One</div>
<div class="step" id="step-two">Two</div>
<div class="step" id="step-three">Three</div>
<div class="step" id="step-four">Four</div>
<div class="step" id="step-five">Five</div>
```

Taking this a step further you could DRY it up so that you can use a single click handler on all the 'Go to X step' buttons:

```js
$('.goto').click(function () {
  $('.step').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index('.goto')).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="goto">Step 1</button>
<button class="goto">Step 2</button>
<button class="goto">Step 3</button>
<button class="goto">Step 4</button>
<button class="goto">Step 5</button><br /><br />

<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step">One</div>
  <div class="step">Two</div>
  <div class="step">Three</div>
  <div class="step">Four</div>
  <div class="step">Five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ozbx36L0/1/):

```
<div class="step active">Step One</div>
<div class="step">Step Two</div>
<div class="step">Step Three</div>
<div class="step">Step Four</div>
<div class="step">Step Five</div>

function nextStep() {
    var activeStep = $('.active');
    $('.step').removeClass('active');
    activeStep.next('.step').addClass('active');
}
```

You need only to save active state, remove active state from all, then apply to next step.